# ESXi on 1 hard drive swapped between servers? Possible?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've come into owning multiple HP DL380's All with no harddrives.

I want to purchase a single ssd and load up ESXi and throw a couple virtual machines on the hard drive.

If I install ESXi/VMs then swap the drive to a different server will each server be able to boot from that harddrive? Or is each instance of ESXi registered to a specific computer?

Comment: I would like to say yes, but I'm not 100% sure.

If I understand well, you want to move your SSD around, and boot/install VM on each of your different HP DL380 ?

Comment: The SSD would contain ESXi and the virtual machines. I just want to move around the SSD and test each server.

Comment: I don't really see any reason why it wouldn't work actually ?

Comment: I was not sure if ESXi registered hardware components and would recognize and deny the use if the hardware had changed.

Comment: I feel it's possible when I read https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1279780-migrate-esxi-to-new-drive/

Comment: If you only move (not copy) the disk, the only problem I could think of would be different MAC adresses on the NICs.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single SSD, you can swap it from server to server with little issue as long as you have enough RAM/CPU to run the VMs you want to run. The only thing tied to the hardware is the license and the hardware profile.

Have you considered using PXE boot from a shared storage?

Comment: I had not thought of this... Looks like what i'm really trying to get at. Thank you for the input, I believe I have some reading to do now.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-60-pxe-boot-esxi.pdf Don't forget to upvote!